# How to read a local xml file into a string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, string, windows-phone-8

In the root of my solution I have a XML file, which content I want to write to a string, because later I parse this string. What is the easiest way in WP8. I dont want to parse anything, just my string to have the content of the xml file, then I use this string the way I do now. Or the file needs to be txt with xml inside, I dont care. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24976378/131809

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

// load the file using;
var xDocument = XDocument.Load(@"C:\MyFile.xml");
// convert the xml into string
string xml = xDocument.ToString();
```

Comment: Im on windows PHONE, so no C:\

Comment: c:\ is an example path.... you could try changing this when you copy / paste it over??

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this :

```
StreamResourceInfo strm = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/myProject;component/States.xml",UriKind.Relative)); 
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strm.Stream);
string xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

[[Nokia developer community wiki: Parse Local XML file in Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Parse_Local_XML_file_in_Windows_Phone)]

or another possible way as shown in this other SO question : [Windows Phone 8 - reading and writing in an existing txt file in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135339/windows-phone-8-reading-and-writing-in-an-existing-txt-file-in-the-project)